# Number of ways of length K to get from the first vertex back to itself in an undirected unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have an undirected unweighted graph with ***N*** vertices numbered from 1 to ***N***. And I need to find the number of ways of length ***K*** to get from the **first** vertex back to itself. It is allowed to revisit the first (or any other) vertex multiple times during that way.
One possible solution is to take an adjacency matrix, find the ***K***-th power of that matrix and then the top left element of the resulting matrix will be the answer to the problem. Time complexity of this method is ***O(N^3 * log(K))***.
But is there a faster approach to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can always do better than `O(N^3 log K)`.

Long answer: The complexity of the fastest approach does depend on how large K is, and, to a smaller extent, the current representation of your graph and the number of edges in the graph. The specific terminology for this problem is "counting closed walks".

### Small K

Use dynamic programming. For a given initial vertex x, we have a 2-dimensional DP state.

> Let DP[ y ][ i ] be the number of walks of length i from our initial
> vertex to y. Then DP[ y ][ 1 ] is 1 if y is adjacent to our initial
> vertex, or 0 otherwise. The recurrence relation for i >
> 1 is: DP[ y ][ i ] is the sum over all neighbors w of y of (DP[ w ][ i - 1 ])

Your answer is then DP[ K ][ 1 ].

Short Python code to do this, assuming graph is an adjacency list representation:

```py
dp = [[0 for _ in range(N + 1)] for _ in range(K + 1)]

for neighbor in graph[1]:
    dp[1][neighbor] = 1

for walk_length in range(2, K + 1):
    for vertex in range(1, N + 1):
        for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
            dp[walk_length][neighbor] += dp[walk_length - 1][vertex]

print(dp[K][1])
```

The time complexity is `O(K * (N + E))`, where E is the number of edges. The extra space complexity is `O(NK)`, which can be reduced to `O(N)` with a small amount of effort. If your graph is dense, it has at worst `|E| = O(N^2)`, so this is `O(K * N * N)`; if your graph is sparse, like a tree, this is `O(K * N)`. Converting between adjacency matrix and adjacency lists is an additive factor of `O(N^2)`.

### Large K

The best answer (complexity-wise) for large K, as far as I have been able to find, is to use a tactic similar to the [adjacency matrix exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527204/if-a-is-the-adjacency-matrix-of-a-graph-why-does-the-i-j-entry-of-an-g) you suggested. That approach is valid, but we can be a bit more clever.

Recall that the adjacency matrix of an unweighted, undirected graph is a real symmetric matrix, and thus it is [diagonalizable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) Let the adjacency matrix be A, and have a spectral decomposition as A = P * D * (P^-1), where D is a diagonal matrix. Then we find the top left element of A^K = P * (D^K) * (P^-1), which requires N exponentiations of single eigenvalues to the Kth power, followed by 2N multiplications and additions.

Since the size of eigenvalues is bounded by the maximum degree, or `O(N)`, the dominating term is determined by the cost of calculating x^K for a number x with O(log N) digits. Determining the time complexity here is complicated: we have to start talking about computational models, and the cost of integer multiplication. Your `O(N^3 log K)` bound works if we're talking about a word RAM model of computation, or a model where machine words are large enough to handle the output. It also works much more generally if you only want the answer modulo some fixed number. Otherwise, if K is arbitrarily large, our N eigenvalue powers can have O(K) bits each, so this last step may take `O( K * N log log N)` time, which is still more efficient than the original full matrix exponentiation (which is at least `O(N^2 * K^2)` in that case).

The complexity of matrix decomposition is closely related to the complexity of matrix multiplication, which is an open problem. It's between N^2 and N^(2.373), but the question of theoretically optimal complexity is [best addressed in math stackexchange questions like this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62904/complexity-of-eigenvalue-decomposition) and usually not relevant in practical problems.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! This cleared things up a bit.